# It is possible when return specific columns in Include of EF core

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I wonder that can we return a specific column in include Ef core

```
        var listAll = _questRepository.GetAll().Include(x => x.QuestItems)
        .AsNoTracking();
```

I want to return some attributes in QuestItems, Is that possible in ef core

Comment: Columns are projected in the `Select` clause. `Include` is only meant to tell EF Core to eagerly load related entities instead of waiting for the code to access them one by one.

Comment: Besides, you didn't post any EF code. A DbContext has no `GetAll()` method and a DbSet<T> is already a single-entity repository. A DbContext is already a multi-entity repository and Unit-of-Work. What you wrote would work only if `GetAll()` simply returns a `DbSet<>`